# Class Not Found Exception when calling readObject

Tags: classnotfoundexception, google-play-games, objectinputstream

I am attempting to use Google Play Game Services in an app of mine to implement turn-based multiplayer. Unfortunately, I am running in to an issue when attempting to load the saved data from a Google Play Match.

Here is my code excerpt:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(match.getData());
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
Object o = in.readObject();
matchData = (MatchData) o;
```

Here is the exception I am getting:

```
08-29 19:11:02.620  20712-20712/com.cor31.letterbetter E/MainMenu﹕ Error loading match data.
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cor31.letterbetter.h
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1638)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:658)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
            at com.cor31.letterbetter.Constants.loadMatchData(Constants.java:134)
            at com.cor31.letterbetter.MainMenuActivity.onActivityResult(MainMenuActivity.java:483)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5643)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3576)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3623)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cor31/letterbetter/h
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1638)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:658)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
            at com.cor31.letterbetter.Constants.loadMatchData(Constants.java:134)
            at com.cor31.letterbetter.MainMenuActivity.onActivityResult(MainMenuActivity.java:483)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5643)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3576)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3623)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cor31.letterbetter.h" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cor31.letterbetter-183.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.cor31.letterbetter-183, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1638)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:658)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)
            at com.cor31.letterbetter.Constants.loadMatchData(Constants.java:134)
            at com.cor31.letterbetter.MainMenuActivity.onActivityResult(MainMenuActivity.java:483)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5643)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3576)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3623)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There is no 'h' class in my project and I don't know why this class is being searched for during readObject. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using proguard to obfuscate your classes?  That would cause the writer to write out a obfuscated name.  By the way, object serialization is pretty heavy duty and fragile (as you are noticing) - maybe look into json or even xml serialization.

Comment: I am obfuscating my code, good catch! I'm going to pursue Gson and see if that'll work for me. Thanks.